# Determining height of ScrollView content

Tags: ios, nativescript, nativescript-vue, nativescript-telerik-ui

I have a Nativescript-Vue application and I'm trying to determine the height of the contained content inside a ScrollView, however when I dump out a variety of height-related properties of the ScrollView both before and after I have changed the sizing of the contained content, there is no difference in the reported heights.

As a bonus question, what I actually care about is determining the state of a contained RadDataForm Picker element (collapsed or expanded) and after having no luck finding anyway to determine this state, I thought I could side-step the issue by looking at the overall height of the RadDataForm which is inside a ScrollView. So if you know how to determine the Picker state, that would be an even better answer.

This is the basic premise of what I've tried:

```js
   let view = this.$refs.scrollView.nativeView;
   let size = view.getActualSize();
   console.dir(size);
   console.log(
      `ht: ${view.height}, ${view.getMeasuredHeight()}, ${view.effectiveHeight}, ${view.scrollableHeight}, ${view.verticalOffset}`
   );
```

The full test code is at this Playground:
https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=SvC31q&v=3

And the API for the ScrollView is here:
https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_ui_scroll_view_.scrollview

I would expect that you could click the button to dump the height state to the console, click on the country Picker and then click on the button again and see the difference in at least one of those properties, but so far, no joy.

Answer (score 0):

Use [scrollableWidth](https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_ui_scroll_view_.scrollview#scrollablewidth) / [scrollableHeight](https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_ui_scroll_view_.scrollview#scrollableheight) on ScrollView to know the actual scrollable width / height.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but if you look at my code sample pasted in the question you will see that I’m already trying that and it doesn’t change.

Comment: Sorry I don't get your point, why it should change? Your data form's height would remain same unless your view is updated, any element is added / removed.

Comment: When you click on a Picker in a RadDataForm the form expands. In the example playground I have provided the DataForm goes from smaller than the ScrollView window to larger than the ScrollView window.

Comment: Can you please confirm whether you are talking about iOS or Android? In Android it's popover which doesn't expand. So I believe it should iOS?

Comment: Yes my current testing has been on iOS. Sorry I hadn’t realised they were implemented differently. I’ll adjust the post tags.

Comment: Also as noted in my post, what I was really after was trying to determine when the Picker has “expanded”, so I guess my workaround won’t work on Android, so if you know how to determine the “expanded” state of the Picker on both iOS and Android that would be even better.

Comment: Android picker works completely different, it won't adjust your original view but just adds a popover which is scrollable itself. May I ask why you would want to know the height when it's expanded, could you explain the purpose behind?

Comment: Yes, as noted above what I really want to know is when someone has clicked on the Picker and is currently editing that value and this seemed to be the only way I could see to do it.

Comment: If you like to receive continuous updates as the editor value is changed, try the property events like [propertyCommitEvent](https://docs.nativescript.org/ns-ui-api-reference/classes/raddataform#propertycommitevent) / [propertyEditedEvent](https://docs.nativescript.org/ns-ui-api-reference/classes/raddataform#propertyeditedevent).

Comment: Those only trigger once someone has changed the value but I need to know when someone has clicked on the Picker and opened it up even before they change the value.

Comment: And yes I’m aware that there is an “editorSelectedEvent” event but it’s iOS only and I need both iOS and Android support.